# Finitely generated Algebra is a field iff is a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a finitely generated $K$-algebra (here, $A$ is also commutative and has a unit).

I'm trying to prove the well-known result that $A$ is a domain if and only if $A$ is a field.

I don't know how to prove that and I'm confused by this example: if $A=K[xy]$, we have that $A\subset K[x,y]$, so it is a finitely generated $K$-algebra. It is clearly a domain, but it is not a field, since $xy$ has no inverse.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your statement is wrong! The correct statement is if $A$ is a $K$-algebra which is a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, then it is a domain if and only if it is a field. There are other variations of course.

Comment: Furthermore your example is flawed. Of course your $A$ is finitely generated but your reasoning fails...Subrings of polynomial rings are not necessarily finitely generated again.

Comment: @MooS I've just realized that this reasoning is wrong in deed.

Comment: Flawed reasoning aside, it was a little overcomplicated considering that $K[x]$ is already a finitely generated algebra that is a counterexample.

Comment: If you want to stick with finitely generated algebras you can prove that if $A$ is a field then $A$ is a finite extension of $K$.

Comment: Perhaps proposition 5.7 of Atiyah and Macdonald is the actual "well-known" result you're referring to: "Let $A\subset B$ be integral domains, $B$ integral over $A$. Then $B$ is a field if and only if $A$ is a field."